# SVN, TRAC and web with Nginx and Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxy, configuration

I have SVN, TRAC and Web server installed in my server.
SVN and TRAC services are configured on Apache, listening 81 port, `http://localhost:81/svn` (with basic http auth) and `http://localhost:81/trac`.

Web server is NGINX, listening 80 port.

I would like to configure nginx to allow access to SVN and TRAC using `http://localhost/svn` and `http://localhost/trac`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Between "**server {**" and "**}**" in your configuration file:

```
location /svn {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:81/svn;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;

        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;

        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_no_cache $cookie_nocache  $arg_nocache $arg_comment;
        proxy_no_cache $http_pragma     $http_authorization;
        proxy_set_header HTTP_AUTHORIZATION $http_authorization;
 }


location /trac {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:81/trac;
        proxy_redirect     off;

        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

        client_max_body_size       10m;
        client_body_buffer_size    128k;

        proxy_connect_timeout      90;
        proxy_send_timeout         90;
        proxy_read_timeout         90;

        proxy_buffer_size          4k;
        proxy_buffers              4 32k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
 }
```